# Can a Selective XML index help when using query()?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, xml

Say I have the following SQL query to work with

```
Select
myxml.query(
'
<go>
{for $each in /This/Company/Department[1]/Role/Person
return if ($each/Shoes/F[@C="9"]="657493742")
then (<ID>{$each/Shoes/F[@C="9916"]/V}</ID>)
else ()}
</go>')
FROM mytable
```

Is there a way to craft a Selective XML index that would help in this situation? According to the documentation it sounds like it could help with filtering the nodes, but I haven't come across any examples of dealing with a query like this.

Comment: Please tag your SQL Server version.

Answer (score 1):

From Selective [XML Indexes (SXI), Supported Features, Prerequisites, and Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/selective-xml-indexes-sxi#supported-features-prerequisites-and-limitations)

> Selective XML indexes support the XQuery supported by SQL Server
>   inside the exist(), value() and nodes() methods.

`query()` is not supported so it will not work for you.

On the other hand it says that

> For the query() and modify() methods, selective XML indexes may be
>   used for node filtering only.

I have not been able to produce a query that use XML indexes using the `query()` method so I can't really tell you in what cases it may work.

If you want to tackle a performance issue with your query I would recommend you to shred the XML using `nodes()` and `value()` and then reconstructing the XML using `for xml path`. It is usually faster than building the XML with `query()` and you could also probably make use of selective XML indexes if you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the query.